# React-Native fetch() equals false before first yield call()

Tags: react-native, fetch, redux-saga, saga, stanza.io

### The issue:

I want to add [stanza.io](https://github.com/legastero/stanza.io) to my react-native project. After some research, I followed [this](https://github.com/MattFoley/react-native-stanza-demo) to install stanza.io. It seems to work pretty well but a problem occurs even before reaching my new stanza-code : I have a `saga` from [`redux-saga`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) whose task is to trigger 2 simultaneous calls to `fetch()` via redux-saga's `yield call()` such as

`const res = yield call(fetch, fetchUrl, { method: 'GET', headers });`

Only the first `yield call(fetch)` fails with the error `uncaught at check call: argument false is not a function`. So I decided to `console.log(fetch)` before every `yield call(fetch)` and discovered that before the first call, `fetch` equals `false`, it is indeed not a function. But for every call after, fetch works perfectly fine and has the right prototype, it is now a function again.

My fetches are triggered this way :

```
const [result1, result2] = yield all([
      call(fetch1, option),
      call(fetch2, option),
    ]);
```

Here is the whole file:

```
import { actionChannel, call, take, put, select, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { device, sanitize } from 'utils';
import config from 'config';
import idx from 'idx';
import moment from 'moment';
import { TradSingleton } from 'trads';
import { LocaleConfig } from 'react-native-calendars';

function* fetchWebTrads(language) {
  try {
    const fetchUrl = `https://example.com/some_route/${language}`;
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    const res = yield call(fetch, fetchUrl, { method: 'GET', headers });
    const response = yield res.json();
    return { trad: response };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
    return { trad: null, error: e };
  }
}

function* fetchMobileTrads(language) {
  try {
    const fetchUrl = `https://example.com/another_route/${language}`;
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    const res = yield call(fetch, fetchUrl, { method: 'GET', headers });
    const response = yield res.json();
    return { trad: response };
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
    return { trad: null, error: e };
  }
}

function* fetchTrads() {
  try {
    moment.locale('en');
    const language = device.getTradLanguage();
    const [mobileTrads, webTrads] = yield all([
      call(fetchMobileTrads, language),
      call(fetchWebTrads, language),
    ]);
    if (mobileTrads.trad && webTrads.trad) {
      moment.locale(language);
      try {
        LocaleConfig.locales[language] = {
          monthNames: moment.months(),
          monthNamesShort: moment.monthsShort(),
          dayNames: moment.weekdays(),
          dayNamesShort: moment.weekdaysShort(),
        };

        LocaleConfig.defaultLocale = language;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Agenda locals fail', e);
      }
      TradSingleton.setLocale(language);
      TradSingleton.setTrads([mobileTrads.trad, webTrads.trad]);
      yield put({ type: 'FETCH_TRADS_SUCCESS' });
    } else {
      yield put({
        type: 'FETCH_TRADS_FAILURE',
        error: !mobileTrads.trad ? mobileTrads.error : webTrads.error,
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error', e);
    yield put({ type: 'FETCH_TRADS_FAILURE', error: e });
  }
}

function* watchFetchTrads() {
  const requestChan = yield actionChannel('FETCH_TRADS');
  while (true) {
    yield take(requestChan);
    yield call(fetchTrads);
  }
}

export default watchFetchTrads;
```

### Software versions:

- React-Native: 0.57.1
- React: 16.5.0

Comment: Can you include more of your code?

Comment: I edited my question and added the whole file.